# What controls the second dimension of tf observations/ what a qnet accepts in its place?

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, tf-agent

Short version. I cant find the variable(s) that control either:

A) The 2nd dimension of a variable in a trajectory, eg the 3 in

```
Trajectory({'action': <tf.Tensor: shape=(64, 3),
```

or B) the number of dimensions a qnet takes during training?

I'm following this tutorial:

https://www.tensorflow.org/agents/tutorials/1_dqn_tutorial

By inserting the prints into the tutorial, as shown below, I extract examples of the following data as it is passed into the training

```
for _ in range(num_iterations):

  # Collect a few steps using collect_policy and save to the replay buffer.
  for _ in range(collect_steps_per_iteration):
    collect_step(train_env, agent.collect_policy)

  # Sample a batch of data from the buffer and update the agent's network.
  experience, unused_info = next(iterator)
  print(experience)
  print(type(experience))
  train_loss = agent.train(experience)
```

Where does the second dimension of shape = (64, 3) in the following output come from?

```
Trajectory(
{'action': <tf.Tensor: shape=(64, 3), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1], .....
```

Below is the only relevant part of the code containing a number 3. Changing it however does nothing.

```
dataset = replay_buffer.as_dataset(
    num_parallel_calls=3, sample_batch_size=batch_size,
    num_steps=n_step_update + 1).prefetch(3)
```

I've been doing my own system similar to this which randomly decided to do dimensions of 2 instead of 3

```
Trajectory(
{'action': <tf.Tensor: shape=(15, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[4, 0],
       [3, 0],
       [3, 3],
       [5, 5],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
```

this personal example is for system playing a game of connect 4.

[4, 0]   the first term i pass in to my system. it is the x dimension of the slot chosen by the machine learning system. its my action. the second term is the slot chosen by the opponent (a simple connect 4 playing script).

I'm having a problem with the dimensions because in my own example it expects 3 instead of 2

> ValueError: The agent was configured to expect a `sequence_length` of '3'....   but at least one of the Tensors in `value` has a time axis dim value '2'

In this example my system does have a dimension of 2... and I believe my qnet (somehow) expects dimensions of 3

Code for my qnet below

```
# this is in my environments initializer (I just thought you needed to see this)

self._action_spec = tf_agents.specs.BoundedArraySpec(
            shape=(), dtype=np.int32, minimum=0, maximum=game.x_rows-1 , name='action')
self._observation_spec = tf_agents.specs.BoundedArraySpec(
            shape=(1, game.x_rows,game.y_rows), dtype=np.float32, minimum=0, name='observation')

######   my qnet  (how does it get the demand of 3 dimensions?)
q_net = tf_agents.networks.q_network.QNetwork(
    input_tensor_spec = the_env.observation_spec(),
    action_spec = the_env.action_spec(),
    preprocessing_layers=None,
    preprocessing_combiner=None,
    conv_layer_params=None,
    fc_layer_params=(75, 40), 
    dropout_layer_params=None,
    activation_fn=tf.keras.activations.relu,
    kernel_initializer=None,
    batch_squash=True,
    dtype=tf.float32,
q_layer_activation_fn=None,
name='QNetwork')
```

Here is the only thing that suggests layer population ... which in my mind is related to the dimensions of the input data... and its nothing like 3 , so why does my q net want 3?

```
fc_layer_params=(75, 40)
```

###############################################

full reproducable code below is here

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tf_agents.networks import q_network
from tf_agents.agents.dqn import dqn_agent
import tf_agents
import tf_agents.environments.py_environment as PyEnvironment 
from tf_agents.trajectories import time_step as ts
import numpy as np
import keras 
import tf_agents.policies.random_tf_policy as random_tf_policy
import tf_agents.environments as tf_py_environment
import math
import numpy as np
import random
import copy
class simple_con_4_game():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x_rows = x
        self.y_rows = y
        self.slots = []
        for i in range(x):
            ys=[]
            for j in range(y):
                ys.append(0)
            self.slots.append(ys)
    def new_game(self):
        for xs in self.slots:
            for slot in xs:
                slot = 0
        
    def check_for_this_line_of_4(self,slot1_indexes,slot2_indexes):
        x1 , y1 , x2 , y2 = slot1_indexes[0] , slot1_indexes[1] , slot2_indexes[0] , slot2_indexes[1]
        x_dif = x1-x2
        y_dif = y1-y2
        players = [1, 2]#  1 = ml      2 = simple script ,    0 = empty 
        for p in players:
            all_good = True
            if self.slots[x1][y1]!=p:
                all_good = False
            for i in range(3):
                try:
                    x_ind = (x_dif*i)+x1
                    y_ind = (y_dif*i)+y1
                    if self.slots[x_ind][y_ind]!=p:
                        all_good = False
                except IndexError:
                    pass
            if all_good:
                return p
        return False

    
    def check_for_any_line_of_4(self):
        a = [-1,0,1]
        for xs, x in zip(self.slots, range(len(self.slots))):
            for slot, y in zip(xs, range(len(xs))):
                for extra_x in a:
                    for extra_y in a:
                        if extra_x != 0 and extra_y != 0:
                            worked = self.check_for_this_line_of_4([x,y],[x+extra_x, y+extra_y])
                            if type(worked)== type(False):
                                pass
                            #elif worked == 1: # ml system won
                            else:
                                return worked
        return False
    
    def find_lowest_slot(self , x):
        lowest_y = 9999
        best_slot = "none"
        for slot, y_ind in zip(self.slots[x], range(len(self.slots[x]))):
            if slot == 0:
                if y_ind < lowest_y:
                    lowest_y = y_ind
        if lowest_y != 9999:
            return lowest_y
        return False
    
    def ml_plays_turn(self, action):
        y = self.find_lowest_slot(action)
        self.slots[action][y] = 1
    
    def script_plays_turn(self, action = 5):
        y = self.find_lowest_slot(action)
        self.slots[action][y] = 1

class Con4Env(PyEnvironment.PyEnvironment):
    
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.game = game
        self._action_spec = tf_agents.specs.BoundedArraySpec(
            shape=(), dtype=np.int32, minimum=0, maximum=game.x_rows-1 , name='action')
        self._observation_spec = tf_agents.specs.BoundedArraySpec(
            shape=(1, game.x_rows,game.y_rows), dtype=np.float32, minimum=0, name='observation')
        self._state = np.zeros((game.x_rows,game.y_rows) , dtype=np.float32)
        self._time_step_spec = ts.time_step_spec(self._observation_spec)
        self._episode_ended = False
        
    def action_spec(self):
        return self._action_spec

    def observation_spec(self):
        return self._observation_spec

    def _reset(self):
        self._state = np.zeros((game.x_rows,game.y_rows) , dtype=np.float32)
        self._episode_ended = False
        return ts.restart(np.array([self._state], dtype=np.float32))
    
    def copy_gameboard_to_state(self):
        for ys, yind in zip(self.game.slots, range(len(self.game.slots))):
            for x , xind in zip(ys, range(len(ys))):
                if x.occupied_by_player:
                    self._state[xind][yind] = 1
                elif x.occupied_by_computer:
                    self._state[xind][yind] = 2
                else:
                    self._state[xind][yind] = 0

    def _step(self, action):
        if self._episode_ended:
            return self.reset()
                               
        lin_found = self.game.check_for_any_line_of_4()
        if type(lin_found) == type(1):
            if lin_found == 1:
                reward = 1
            elif lin_found == 2:
                reward = -1
            self._episode_ended = True
        elif self.game.ml_plays_turn(action):
            self.game.script_plays_turn()
            self.copy_gameboard_to_state()
        else:
            reward = -0.05 #### column full,     call it draw 
            self._episode_ended = True
                               
        if self._episode_ended: #### if game was ended last round the reward then we go in here 1 last time
            lin_found = self.game.check_for_any_line_of_4()
            if type(lin_found) == type(1):
                if lin_found == 1:
                    reward = 1
                elif lin_found == 2:
                    reward = -1
                self._episode_ended = True
            else:
                reward = -0.05 #### column full,     call it draw 
                self._episode_ended = True  
                               
            self.game.new_game()
            return ts.termination(np.array([self._state], dtype=np.float32), reward)
        else:
            return ts.transition(np.array([self._state], dtype=np.float32), reward=0.0, discount=0.0)
        
            
            
            
game = simple_con_4_game(20 , 20)
the_env = Con4Env(game)
eval_env = Con4Env(game)
the_env = tf_py_environment.TFPyEnvironment(the_env)
eval_env = tf_py_environment.TFPyEnvironment(eval_env)

from tf_agents.utils import common
step_type_spec = tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.dtypes.int32, name='step_type')
reward_spec= tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.dtypes.float32, name='reward_spec')
discount_spec= tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.dtypes.float32, name='discount_spec')
time_step_spec = tf_agents.trajectories.TimeStep( step_type_spec ,reward_spec, discount_spec, the_env.observation_spec() )

q_net = tf_agents.networks.q_network.QNetwork(
    input_tensor_spec = the_env.observation_spec(),
    action_spec = the_env.action_spec(),
    preprocessing_layers=None,
    preprocessing_combiner=None,
    conv_layer_params=None,
    fc_layer_params=(75, 40),
    dropout_layer_params=None,
    activation_fn=tf.keras.activations.relu,
    kernel_initializer=None,
    batch_squash=True,
    dtype=tf.float32,
    q_layer_activation_fn=None,
    name='QNetwork'
)

train_step_counter = tf.Variable(0)
gamma = 0.99
min_q_value = -20  # @param {type:"integer"}
max_q_value = 20  # @param {type:"integer"}
n_step_update = 2  # @param {type:"integer"}
agent = dqn_agent.DqnAgent( 
    time_step_spec , 
    the_env.action_spec() , 
    q_net, 
    optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.000001),

    n_step_update=n_step_update,
    td_errors_loss_fn=common.element_wise_squared_loss,
    gamma=gamma,
    train_step_counter=train_step_counter
    
)

random_policy = random_tf_policy.RandomTFPolicy(time_step_spec, the_env.action_spec())

def compute_avg_return(environment, policy, num_episodes=10):
    total_return = 0.0
    for _ in range(num_episodes):
        time_step = environment.reset()
        episode_return = 0.0
        while not time_step.is_last():
            action_step = policy.action(time_step)
            time_step = environment.step(action_step.action)
            episode_return += time_step.reward

        total_return += episode_return

    avg_return = total_return / num_episodes
    return avg_return.numpy()[0]


compute_avg_return(the_env, random_policy , num_episodes= 3 )

# data collector 

from tf_agents.utils import common
import copy
#@test {"skip": true}
replay_buffer_capacity = 999
initial_collect_steps = 100
batch_size = 15
n_step_update = 1

replay_buffer = tf_agents.replay_buffers.TFUniformReplayBuffer(
    data_spec=agent.collect_data_spec,
    batch_size=the_env.batch_size,
    max_length=replay_buffer_capacity
)

def collect_step(environment, policy):
    time_step = environment.current_time_step()
    action_step = policy.action(time_step)
    next_time_step = environment.step(action_step.action)
    traj = tf_agents.trajectories.from_transition(time_step, action_step, next_time_step)
    replay_buffer.add_batch(traj)

for _ in range(initial_collect_steps):
    collect_step(the_env, random_policy)

dataset = replay_buffer.as_dataset(
num_parallel_calls=2, sample_batch_size=batch_size,
num_steps=n_step_update + 1).prefetch(2)
iterator = iter(dataset)

# this bugga needs to work
# Training the agent

from tf_agents.utils import common
import copy
num_eval_episodes = 50
num_iterations = 30
collect_steps_per_iteration = 200

the code in a graph using TF function.
agent.train = common.function(agent.train)
agent.train_step_counter.assign(0)

# Evaluate the agent's policy once before training.
avg_return = compute_avg_return(eval_env, agent.policy, num_eval_episodes)
returns = [avg_return]

for _ in range(num_iterations):
    for __ in range(collect_steps_per_iteration):
        collect_step(the_env, agent.collect_policy)

# Sample a batch of data from the buffer and update the agent's network.
    
    experience, unused_info = next(iterator)
    print("exp   bellow       &*&*&*&*&*&* ")
    print(experience)           ####################        <<<===========   THIS OBJECT IS PROBLEM  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    print(type(experience))
    print("exp   above    ,   num below   ")
    print(_)
    train_loss = agent.train(experience)  # takes tf_agents.typing.types.NestedTensor    but im passing trajectory

    step = agent.train_step_counter.numpy()

    if step % log_interval == 0:
        print('step = {0}: loss = {1}'.format(step, train_loss.loss))

    if step % eval_interval == 0:
        avg_return = compute_avg_return(eval_env, agent.policy, num_eval_episodes)
        print('step = {0}: Average Return = {1:.2f}'.format(step, avg_return))
        returns.append(avg_return)
```

Comment: Please see how to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: hi, i managed to cut the code down to a few hundred lines by gutting the ai of the game and cutting loads of stuff out

Comment: Your question contains a lot of unneeded information

Answer (score 1):

The (64,3) second dimension (3) comes from `n_step_update + 1`:

```
dataset = replay_buffer.as_dataset(
    num_parallel_calls=3, sample_batch_size=batch_size,
    num_steps=n_step_update + 1).prefetch(3)
```